# angularjs $scope doesn't show data in html view, but data is shown in console

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Im trying to read data from my database to my view in my application in the web browser. Problem is that I can't get any data to show. The data is shown in the console, so it's connecting to the database but somehow it doesn't print the data in the view.

[Data is showing in console but not in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1reE.jpg)

**playerDetails.php**

```
include 'database_connections.php';

$sql = "SELECT idPlayer, PlayerName, PlayerEmail, PlayerPassword, 
PlayerTeam FROM Players";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$data =  array();
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $data[] = $row;
  }
 } else {
  echo "0 results";
 }

 mysqli_close($conn);
 echo json_encode($data);
```

**angular-script.js (Controller)**

```
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp',[]);

crudApp.controller('DbController', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("DatabaseFiles/playerDetails.php")
 .then(function (response) {$scope.players = response.data;
 console.log(response.data)
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='crudApp'>
<head>
<title>Crud app</title>

<script src="js/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="DbController">

    <table >
      <tr>
        <th>Player ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Team</th>
      </tr>

      <tr ng-repeat="players in Players | orderBy:'-created'">
        <td>{{players.idPlayer}}</td>
        <td>{{players.PlayerName}}</td>
        <td>{{players.PlayerEmail}}</td>
        <td>{{players.PlayerPassword}}</td>
        <td>{{players.PlayerTeam}}</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="js/angular-script.js"></script>
</body>
```

**SOLVED**

Im not sure what caused the problem but I created a new database and a new project and did the following changes to my PlayerController.js (former "angular-script.js") and index.html

**PlayerController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('crudApp', []);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('PlayerRead.php').then(function(response) {
    $scope.users = response.data;
    console.log(response.data);
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
  <title>Crud app</title>
  <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
    angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js" 
  ></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="crudApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Player ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Team</th>
    </tr>

    <tr ng-repeat="user in users track by $index">
     <td>{{user.PlayerID}}</td>
     <td>{{user.PlayerName}}</td>
     <td>{{user.PlayerEmail}}</td>
     <td>{{user.PlayerTeam}}</td>
   </tr>

  </table>

  <script src="PlayerController.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I can see in the inspector that ng-repeat is printed multiple times but it prints empty slots with no data.

Answer (score 1):

Make it as below line, as it is case sensitive.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="player in players | orderBy:'-created'">
       <td>{{player.idPlayer}}</td>
       <td>{{player.PlayerName}}</td>
       <td>{{player.PlayerEmail}}</td>
       <td>{{player.PlayerPassword}}</td>
       <td>{{player.PlayerTeam}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Tried that but still same problem, data in console but not in view.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `players in players  | orderBy:'-created'`